# my data saved in one column in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to save data, but there is error that my `data2` save in `column1`. I've added the data as array like

```
$simpan array(
 'column1' = $data1,
 'column2' = $data2,
 'column3' = $data3
);
```

But doesn't want to save to my database.

```
public function simpannilaidetail(){
    $id_nilai = $this->input->post('id_nilai');
    $id_pelajaran = $this->input->post('id_pelajaran');
    $get = $this->modelpenilaian->datanilai($id_nilai, $id_pelajaran);
    if (count($get) > 0) {
        $rs = "";
    }else{
        $nilaiawal = '0';

        **$rs = $this->crudmodel->simpannilaifix($id_nilai, $id_pelajaran, $nilaiawal);**   
    }

    echo $rs;
} 

public function simpannilaifix($idn,$idp,$nilaiawal){
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO nilaidetail values('$idn','$idp','$nilaiawal')");
}
```

It's saved but the result is :

```
column1      column2    column3
data1,data2     NULL       data3
```

the correct result must be like this :

```
column1 column2 column3
data1     data2    data3
```

thanks

Comment: why don't you use ci query builder to insert the data

Comment: I've do it but no data saved if using ci query builder because im trying to save data in onclick ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Either use  normal query like this

*You should provide column name also*

```
public function simpannilaifix($idn,$idp,$nilaiawal)
{
    /*change column_name with your real table column name*/

    $sql = "INSERT INTO nilaidetail (column_name1, column_name2, column_name3) 
            values('".$idn."','".$idp."','".$nilaiawal."')";
    $this->db->query($sql);
    echo $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Or you can use  ci insert query builder :

```
public function simpannilaifix($idn,$idp,$nilaiawal)
{
    /*change column_name with your real table column name*/

    $data = array('column_name1' => $idn,
                  'column_name2' =>$idp,
                  'column_name3' => $nilaiawal
            );
    $this->db->insert('nilaidetail',$data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data

Comment: doesn't save any data that why I ask here, If I'm save data with ci query builder no data saved but if I trying to save using my code the problem is data2 saved on coloumn1

Comment: ok you should provide column name also with table in your query, see my updated answer for that

Comment: problem solved. I forget to add ' between , on my onlick statement (wrong)onclick="function('data1,data2')" (right)onclick="function('data1','data2')" ... thank you for your help